# why does F# failwith return a generic type rather than Exception type

Tags: exception, f#, fsi

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/the-failwith-function) the failwith function returns an `Exception`
But the function signature is `string -> 'a`

Why is the signature not `string -> Exception` ?

Comment: As a side note I'm running 10.4.0 of FSharp Interactive, and if I execute `failwith "Kaboom!";;` I get 

stdin(3,1): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type
    val it : '_a
Either define 'it' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

Comment: The value restriction error is specific to FSI. When you evaluate any particular expression, if the type can't be inferred you might get an error like this. If you send smaller pieces of code to FSI in one command (e.g. one line instead of 10) then it has less context to make a type inference. However, you can force the type by using a type argument: `failwith<unit> "Kaboom!"`

Comment: ahh I see, because it is returning a generic type and fsi cant infer what type it might be. Cryptic error messages... death by a thousand cuts..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The docs don't say that `failwith` returns an `Exception`. It says it *generates* an F# exception. The exception system is separate from the normal control flow of returning values. Hence the name, it's *exceptional*.

Exceptions, when "thrown" (which is a less ambiguous term than "generated" as used in the docs, I think), will travel up the stack until encountering a `try ... with` construct that handles this particular type of exception, or if not will terminate the program. See [the F# docs on exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/) for details.

`failwith` returns `'a` so that it can be used anywhere, since `'a` can be inferred to be anything. It can pretend to return anything because it never actually returns at all, unlike most functions, it always throws an exception instead. If it had returned `Exception` it would only be able to be used in expressions that are expected to evaluate to `Exception`, which are exceptionally unusual since exceptions are usually thrown, not returned. For example, given:

```
if i > 0 then
  i
else
  failwith "i is negative"
```

If `failwith` had returned `Exception`, the compiler would complain here about an `int`  being expected instead of an `Exception` since the first branch evaluates to an `int`. But since `failwith` returns an `'a` instead, it's inferred to be an `int` itself and everything is fine.

Comment: Once you mentioned that exceptions are thrown, then penny dropped. You are completely correct that exceptions are not returned ! Ta

Comment: FYI; in other languages methods that never returns has the return type `Nothing` which is kind of the opposite of object. Very useful!